# How can I compute the Fourier transform a a product of two functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I think I understood the basic rule but cannot apply it in practice with more difficult examples than the ones consisting in basic functions. Convention for Fourier transform I use is the following:
\begin{equation}
\hat{f}(k)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{ikx}f(x)dx
\end{equation}
If I should find what is $\hat{u}(k)$ of the function $u(x)=sign(x)e^{-\left|x\right|}$, what can I do once written the integral:
\begin{equation}
\hat{u}(k)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{ikx}sign(x)e^{-\left|x\right|}dx \text{     ?}
\end{equation}

Comment: This case is easy, if you break the integration into the ranges $x\ge0$ and $x\le0$ separately.  You get something like $1/(1+ik)-1/(1-ik)$.

Comment: It doesn't work so great here, but the convolution theorem for the Fourier transform can be useful for other pairs of functions.

Comment: @kimchilover thank you!! I get the opposite signs: is it just a convention or am I making something wrong in the computation?

Comment: No, it's my mistake.   $\int_0^\infty \exp(-x +ikx)dx=1/(1-ik)$, and so on.